# Android Toolbar keeps black Background, wont hide

Tags: java, android

With Android, I am using a "Galaxy S10", when creating a APP I am trying to hide the Top Nav and Bottom Action Bars.

I Looked up many documents non seem to work, I am using "ConstraintLayout".

Here is my some of my code:

in Main() function:

```
    private View decoreView;

    decoreView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decoreView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if(visibility == 0)
                decoreView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
        }
    });
```

And rest of code:

```
private  int hideSystemBars() {
        return View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
}

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            if(hasFocus) {
                decoreView.setSystemUiVisibility(hideSystemBars());
            }
    }
```

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

I am not using Kotlin yet, keeping with Java. Any Help would be appriciated.

[Screenshot of Problem with Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iYdI.jpg)

Comment: I can't see "status bar" nor "bottom navigation bar" in your screen shot... What else are you trying to hide?

Comment: The problem is not that the "Status Bar" or "Naviagtion bar" are gone, when the top Status bar is hidden, their is a black area at least on S10 and above, if you look taht screenshot has a Black area on top, thats the area that i would like to expand into.


What I noticed, even though i said "go to Full screen" Initially its set to "Auto" on phone settings: Settings->Display->Full Screen Apps. When set to "Full Screen" it removes that black bar. But how do i make that "Default to Full Screen" and not Auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand right but If you want is to hide the toolbar you can just change the theme in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

change this for something like

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I hope this can help you :P

Comment: Yes, this got the "Status Bar" to hide, problem is I found out, that Apps are Defaulted in settings -> Display -> Full Screen Apps, to Auto, not Full screen, is their a way to make this setting only allow "Full Screen"?

Comment: I'm not sure witch setting are you talking about, but if you want is to play the app in full screen you just need to implement the theme for that

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

Comment: and also add to the manifest

<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>

I hope this can help you